# Representing Data Types With Variable Variables

Tags: haskell, typeclass, algebraic-data-types

I am attempting to represent formulae with variables ranging over, for instance, either formulae or variables and constants:

```
R(a,b) -> Q   [Q takes formulae as substitutions]
R(x,b) v P(b) [x takes constants or variables as substitutions]
```

Functions over formulae have class constraints specifying which variable type is being considered. For instance, classes of terms, variables and substitutions might have the following structure:

```
class Var b where ...
class (Var b) => Term b a | b -> a where ...
class (Term b a) => Subst s b a | b a -> s where ...
```

There are many algorithms dealing with syntactic term manipulation for which parameterizing term types on variable types would be beneficial. For instance, consider a generic unification algorithm over formulae of some term type having different variable types:

```
unify :: (Subst s b a) => a -> a -> s b a
unify (P -> F(a,b)) ((Q v R) -> F(a,b)) = {P\(Q v R)}  -- formulae
unify (P(x,f(a,b))) (P(g(c),f(y,b)))    = {x\g(c),y\a} -- variables and constants
```

What is the **best** way to represent such variable variables? I have experimented with a variety of methods, but haven't settled on a **satisfactory** solution.

Comment: I am having trouble painting a clear picture of your problem.  For example, in your `R(x,b) v P(b)` example, is `b` considered a variable?  If formulae are allowed more than one variable, and we are to constrain variable ranges, then the free variables must appear somewhere in the type of the term.  Could you give a few examples of what kinds of things you are trying to characterize, or a simple example of an algorithm that could make use of these constraints?

Comment: I updated the question with an example of a unification algorithm that could accept the same "term type" with different "variable types." Writing the algorithm isn't difficult; what I'm having trouble with is representing the underlying "term type" and "variable type" relationship. In the original example, `R(x,b) v P(b)` was supposed to be a term with free variables and constants in a term language.

Comment: Your notation is confusing me.  Can you try to use standard Haskell syntax?  Also, what is the constraint `Subst s b a` supposed to represent?  I understand you are probably thinking at a pretty abstract level, perhaps having been immersed in this problem for a while, but you've got to bring it down to earth for us to help you.  What have you tried, what was not satisfactory about what you tried?

Comment: `Subst s b a` is intended to be a class of substitutions `s` of variables `b` in terms `a`. I deliberately mixed PROLOG and Haskell notation because it is reminiscent of PROLOG and the normal unification we run on uninterpreted terms. I essentially want to "type" different variables: on the one hand, perform unification with "formula-level" logic variables; on the other, perform unification with "term-level" logic variables over ground terms and (predicate logic) variables Hopefully this is helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your question would be clearer if you said what was wrong with the following simple minded representation of terms and formulas? There are a million ways of doing this sort of thing (the possibilities much expanded by `{-LANGUAGE GADTs-}`)

```
  {-#LANGUAGE TypeOperators#-}

  data Term v c = Var v 
                | Const c deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

  data Formula p v c = Atom p 
                     | Term v c := Term v c 
                     | Formula p v c :-> Formula p v c 
                     | Not (Formula p v c)
                     | Subst v (Term v c) (Formula p v c) 
                     | Inst p (Formula p v c) (Formula p v c) 
                     deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)


  update f v c v' = case v == v' of True -> c; False -> f v'

  one = Const (1:: Int)
  zero = Const (0 :: Int)
  x = Var 'x'
  y = Var 'y'
  p = Atom 'p'
  q = Atom 'q'
  absurd = one := zero
  brouwer p = (((p :-> absurd) :-> absurd) :-> absurd) :-> (p :-> absurd)

  ref ::  (v -> c) -> Term v c -> c
  ref i (Var v)  = i v
  ref i (Const c) = c

  eval :: (Eq c , Eq v , Eq p) => (v -> c) -> (p -> Bool) -> Formula p v c -> Bool
  eval i j (Atom p) = j p
  eval i j (p := q) = ref i p == ref i q
  eval i j (p :-> q) = not ( eval i j p) ||  eval i j q
  eval i j (Not p) = not (eval i j p)
  eval i j q@(Subst v t p) =  eval (update i v (ref i t)) j q
  eval i j q@(Inst p r s) = eval i (update j p (eval i j r)) s
```

Comment: Why don't you make those constructor names a little more opaque? :-p

Comment: I had better ones in scope, but in a worse arrangement, I edited to introduce more suggestive ones.

Comment: This approximates my first solution. The problem is that I want a more generic notion of terms and variables so that I could write, e.g., a single unification algorithm that would be able to accept "variable arguments" for the same type of terms. I'll play around with your suggestion more, however, and see if I can modify it so that functions over it are suitably general. Thanks for the help; I'll accept your answer if no-one responds within a few days. I think what I'm looking for might be found hidden in packages like SYB or Uniplate (i.e., generics).